# Styling my form in twig & php

Tags: html, forms, render, twig

Just wanted to know how I can separate the textbox from the label when creating a form in html twig using formbuilder? The form works fine, but I want to align each new textbox and the text beneath the previous so that it doesn't look as sloppy. Is there a way I can render the form, then style it? I'm using php to create the form with formBuilder, and rendering it with twig.

the php for creating the form looks like this:

```
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder(array('csrf_protection' => false))
        ->add('username','text', array('label'=>'Username/Alias'))          
        ->add('password','password',array('label'=>'Password'))
        ->add('ve','text',array('label'=>'Verification code'))
        ->getForm() ;
    $request=  $this->getRequest();
```

And the twig looks like so:

```
<form action="{{path('myBundle_login')}}" method="post" enctype={{form_enctype(form)}}>
// the form_enctype(form) is the form that is sent through

{{ form_errors(form) }}

{{ form_widget(form) }}

{{ form_rest(form) }}
```

but i just want it neatly spaced... please help.

Answer (score 1):

This page can help you http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-row-form-name-variables

specialy this two functions `form_row(form.name)` and `` `form_label(form.name) ``

Answer (score 1):

if you want a common style for all forms,
apply a common css like below

```
form div label
{
/*your css here*/
}
form div input
{
/*your css here*/
}
```

and if you want to style each one as per your wish

```
 <div>
    {{ form_errors(form.name) }}    
   <div>
      <div> 
         {{ form_label(form.name) }}
      </div>
   </div>

   <div> 
    <div>
     {{ form_widget(form.name,{'attr': {'class': 'yourclassname'} }) }}
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

this will neatly space your form